# @dblookup not retrieving multiple values

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Hi I have this issue that I really don't know why its happening. It seems my @dblookup is not returning a multiple value. I does retrieve a value but its only one.This is my whole formula code:

```
class:=  "";
mode:= "";
server:= "";
db:= "";
lkpView:= "AllExpenseItem";
key:= @Text(CVNo);
colNum:= 2;
fieldName:="Product_Category";
list:= @Explode(@DbLookup(class:mode;server:db;lkpView;key;fieldName);";");
@If(@IsError(list);@Unavailable;list);
```

the lkpView's 1st column is sorted and categorized.Is there a problem on my code or did I miss something that's why its not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the my problem by making the lkpView not hidden, I don't know why its not working on hidden views though. Now it returns a multiple value as expected.

Comment: Hidden ? Do you mean "visible from Notes" (V in the views list ?)
You can also get detail on the error by displaying @ promt([ok] ; @text(list) ... ) or even better affect the @ DbLookup to a variable and @text it

Comment: yeah something like that Emmanuel, I really don't know what happened because I tried to do it with a hidden view before and it works. I tried not hiding the view and it suits well.

Comment: @DbLookup has worked correctly in hidden views for more than 20 years. I very strongly doubt that was actually your problem. But I'm glad it's working for you now.

Comment: Yes Richard I totally agree with you, and I've been using @dblookup ever since I've learned notes. That's why I'm very confused what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the view make sure you put parenthesis around the view name.

```
class:=  "";
mode:= "";
server:= "";
db:= "";
lkpView:= "(AllExpenseItem)";
key:= @Text(CVNo);
colNum:= 2;
fieldName:="Product_Category";
list:= @Explode(@DbLookup(class:mode;server:db;lkpView;key;fieldName);";");
@If(@IsError(list);@Unavailable;list);
```

Comment: I'm actually using the alias of the view ken. Thanks for the answer though.